# Failed to resolve: com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.0

Tags: androidimageslider

I am trying to use ImageSlider library from this github
But always failed to resolve when trying to sync the project implementation
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix0Bj.png)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). You should put own reaserch efforts into solving your problem,
show what you have tried and add a brief description of your efforts plus the actual code that you have written plus the precise problem that you're facing.
Also: please [don't upload code, results or data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Copy

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

Paste it inside your **settings.gradle** file. [image]